# Autotest not running after changes to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, autotest, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3.0.3, Rspec 2, Zentest gem - extremely frustrated right now, so give me some slack.

1. Why doesn't autotest rerun my integration (/request) and controller specs why I make changes to a view file? Am I missing something? It works fine when I make changes to my controller or spec file.
2. How do I make it do so?
3. Is there documentation that isn't like a swamp to wade through to figure out where the magic configuration incantations for autotest/zentest/etc are? It just seems like a big mess to me, so please tell me how dumb I am and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that this is the default behavior when you run autotest with Rspec, that is, changes to view templates will only re-run the specs for the template.

Looking through the ZenTest docs won't help much, since the test framework (RSpec in this case) is where spec-file to view-file mapping actually occurs.

You can add new mappings in the `.autotest` file as described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645346/ruby-autotest-with-add-mapping). I'd also take a look in the RSpec code itself to see all the mappings in one place, which can be found in  `{path_to_installed_gems}/rspec-rails-{version}/lib/autotest/rails_rspec2.rb`